# Android: WIFI and Mobile internet confliction

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-service, android-wifi

In my android app I have to send a request for a server to receive its response. The application works fine and when I was doing some tests found the following issue.

Think WIFI is switched OFF and Mobile(3G) connection is available. So if I switch ON the WIFI just after when I press the button to send the request to server, the application Stops executing from the line in the following code `resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();`. This code runs in a seperate thread and Using a Handler class.

I think that happens because when I presss the button(To send request) it only have mobile(3G) internet and trying to process with that(Mobile Internet). But again when I switch on WIFI while processing, may be trying to process with WIFI as WIFI has the highest priority and make the confliction.

Does anyone have any Idea of how to prevent this confliction.

**Edits.**.......................................................

```
InputStream in = null; 
int resCode = -1; 

     try 
     {                                                                                             
        URL url = new URL(urlStr.replace(" ", "%20"));                                             
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();                                             
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConn;                                  
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);                                                   
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);                                                
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");                                                           
        httpConn.connect(); 
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(5500);        Log.v("State", "before get response code");                                                            
 /*->>*/ resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();    Log.v("State", "After get response code");                                                            
        in = (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) ? httpConn.getInputStream() : in;              

    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();                                                                              
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();                                                                               
    }
```

The last line it successfully executes in this case is `httpConn.setConnectTimeout(5500);` and stop executing from there....

It Runs `"before get response code"` but not `"before get response code"` in Logcat....

Even it doesn't go for any exception... I checked...

Comment: by "terminate" do you mean force close? can you capture a logcat of the event?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, I have used a ProgressDialog while it receive the server response. Most of the times progress dialog starts and it never ends[It does not Receive the server response]. Several times "force close" and terminated

Comment: like i said, post a logcat of the session.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, I added the code and the place where it stucks by checking the logcat in the edits part in my question...

Comment: Switch the order of `connect()` and `setConnectTimeout()`. Also are you using an AsyncTask?

Comment: Hi WarrenFaith, I am Using a Handler(Not AsyncTask). And also I interchanged both the lines. But Still its there......

Comment: do you know that the server you are connecting to is not simply hanging? print out the URL, and paste it into a browse (or use curl) and make sure the response is coming back. and, WarrenFaith is right, you should set the timeout before calling `connect()`.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, Yes I tested in this way(using browser) and it works fine. Also it works prety well in the phone. The problem occurs if I switch ON the WIFI just after when I request the response from server, While processing the request with the mobile Internet(3G)